# How get for second match group with number?

Tags: php, regex, regex-group

Text for example

```
data=1 type=old
data=2 type=test (2)
type=test data=3 (3)
```

I need get data-id from 2 and 3 lines

My code:

```
(data=([\d]+)|type=test)\s+(?!\1)((?1))
```

but don't get data=3

Comment: `data=(\d+)(?=.*\(\d+\)$)`, or `data=(\d+)(?=.*\(\1\)$)`? What are the pattern requirements?

Comment: sorry, i need get only 2 and 3 lines (type=test), for this reason add type=test in regex

Comment: `^(?=.*type=test).*data=(\d+)` or `^(?=.*type=test).*data=\K\d+`

Comment: this example is short, is original data=2 type=test etc_tag=know

Answer (score 1):

You need the `g` from global and `m` from multiline in your regex:

```
/(data=([\d]+)|type=test)\s+(?!\1)((?1))/gm
```

Answer (score 0):

In the most simple form you may use

```
^(?=.*type=test).*data=(\d+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oKF4gk/1)

You may add word/whitespace boundaries later if necessary, e.g.

```
^(?=.*\btype=test\b).*\bdata=(\d+)\b
^(?=.*(?<!\S)type=test(?!\S)).*(?<!\S)data=(\d+)(?!\S)
```

The  point is

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=.*type=test)` - there must be `type=test` after any 0+ chars as many as possible to the right of the current position
- `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `data=` - a string
- `(\d+)` - Group 1: 1+ digits